# How did the Galactic Republic build Acclamator class ships so fast

Tags: star-wars

We see in the Battle of Geonosis in Attack of the Clones that the clone army had Acclamator-Class assault ships, but how did they get them? How did Kuat Drive Yards design and produce a warship so fast without any notice?

Comment: How do you know they had no notice?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of an answer in Canon, I've seen a claim about a piece of the script that may suggest they've been working on it since they started the Clone army, but I've not seen any confirmation